# How to pass Form Control value to custom Validator Function's Parameter in Angular 5 Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

```
this.FormGroupName = this.formBuilder.group({
  reason: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  category: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, this.checkCategoryInput(this.whatHappenedFormGroup.controls.category.value, this.categoryList)])]
});
```

I am getting the error: `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined` in the browser.

I'm guessing that I have to check if the category control value is null or not. I tried doing this in the function, but it seems it needs to be done earlier.

Does anyone have a recommendation for how to pass the category value into my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap it in a private form field which contains an arrow function, otherwise it's executed at component creation, instead of validation:

```
export class CategoryFormComponent {
  private categoryValidator = (control: AbstractControl) => {
    return this.checkCategoryInput(control.value, this.categoryList);
  };


  this.whatHappenedFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    reason: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    category: ['', Validators.compose([
      Validators.required, 
      this.categoryValidator
    ])]
  });
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I copy pasted your code and I still get the same error on the line `this.whatHappenedFormGroup.controls.category.value,`

Comment: what's `whatHappenedFormGroup`? where do you define it?

Comment: That form group should also be in the place of `FormGroupName`. I was attempting to rename my variables for the question, but missed this one. It is declared like this: `public whatHappenedFormGroup: FormGroup;`

Comment: Exactly the elegant solution I was looking for. This answers so many questions about Validation for me in general, thank you.

Comment: @masu9 you're welcome! I see I had forgotten to add `this.` but you figured it out :) glad i could help